# Unable to formulate a regex with recurring pattern

Tags: regex, python-2.7

I am trying to write a regex in python that can return me groups of similar patterns. Here are some sample inputs -

- `class:('MF YY' or 'XX') and status:('Active' or 'Pending')`
- `class:('MF YY' or 'XX') and status:('Active' or 'Pending') and available:1`
- `available:1`
- `available:1 or class:('MF YY' or 'XX' or 'YY')`
  *`status:'Pending'`

And many such combinations. I want the output to be in following format -

**Input:** `class:('MF YY' or 'XX' or 'YY') and status:('Active' or 'Pending') or available:1`

**Output:**

```
group 1: class:('MF YY' or 'XX' or 'YY')
group 2: and
group 3: status:('Active' or 'Pending')
group 4: or
group 5: available:1
```

Here's the regex I wrote -

```
(\w*\:\(.*?\))(?:\s*(and|or)*\s*)
```

This returns me -

```
group 1: class:('MF YY' or 'XX')
group 2: and
```

I can change the regex to -

```
(\w*\:\(.*?\))(?:\s*(and|or)*\s*)+(\w*\:\(.*?\))
```

to return -

```
group 1: class:('MF YY' or 'XX')
group 2: and
group 3: status:('Active' or 'Pending')
```

However, my approach above is not scalable if more expressions are added. I tried adding * / + for recurrence, but that did not work.

How do I achieve recurring patterns that are of 3 types -

1. field:('{something}' and/or {something} ...)
2. field:{something}
3. and/or operators that combine these smaller expressions

Thanks in advance for all the help.

Comment: There is no scalable solution that can capture everything in a separate capture group - unless you write code to generate the regex pattern. Why not repeatedly apply the same pattern to the input until all matches have been found?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would capture each using an or operator (`|`):

```
\w+:\([^)]+\)|\w+:'[^']+'|\w+:\S+|(?:and|or)
```

The first part `\w+:\([^)]+\)` gets the `field:('{something}' and/or {something} ...)`

The second part `\w+:'[^']+'` gets the `field:'{something}'`

The third part `\w+:\S+` gets the `field:{something}`

And the last part gets the operators.

Regex work from left to right, so that the first part is always checked before trying to match the second, third, fourth, etc parts.

Use the above with `re.findall` to get a list of each match.

[ideone demo](http://ideone.com/9NwebE)